# What command line parameters do piqic and piqi accept?

Tags: erlang

The help section in the script is less than usefull I was wondering if anyone knows where the docs are for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piqi author here.

Meaningful `piqic erlang` command-line parameters are mentioned in Piqi for Erlang User’s Manual: http://piqi.org/doc/erlang

I will put together a separate section that lists all the command-line parameters, in the meantime, you might be interested in those:

- `--normalize true` - convert "CamelCase"-style identifiers from the original type spec into "camel-case" Erlang names
- `--gen-defaults` - generate default constructors for the data types; they look like `default_<type-name>/0` in the generated code.
- `-C <dir>` - specify output directory for the generated code.

Command-line parameters for `piqi` are fairly well documented at http://piqi.org/doc/tools